Using eigenvalues of an differential operator to numerically solve another differential equation and use the solutions to perform integration
I am trying to use eigenvalues of a differential operator in another differential equation to find solutions of the later. Next I want to use the solutions to perform a numerical integration where I want to use solutions for two different eigenvalues. 
plain text code:
a = NDEigenvalues[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + u[x], u[x], {x, -5, 5},4];(* a[[n]] gives the nth eigenvalue *)

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a[[n]]*y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {n}]; (* I want to use the nth eigenvalue a[[n]] in the second line and find the solution such that the solution can be accessed using pfun[x][n] the parameter n for performing integration later*)

s[n_, m_] := NIntegrate[pfun[x][n]*x*pfun[x][m], {x, 0, 1}](* Trying to define s that can be accessed using parameter n and m *)


The error message is clear. You can't type a[[n]] where n has no value. If you also post plain text code you used., may be someone could show you how to do what you want in other ways.

I want to use eigenvalues of an differential operator in another differential equation. Numerically solve the second differential equation such that the solutions can be accessed using a parameter to be used in an integration later.

@SadmanSakib welcome to MSE. Your approach just need a little adjustment. Nasser answer is a neat way to treat also. Good luck.

You are making things too complicated. Why not just write a function that takes n,m and each time do the NDSolve on each?
a = NDEigenvalues[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + u[x], u[x], {x, -5, 5}, 4];
s[n_Integer, m_Integer] := Module[{pn, pm, y, t,x},
  pn = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a[[n]]*y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}]; 
  pm = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a[[m]]*y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}]; 
  NIntegrate[pn[x]*x*pm[x], {x, 0, 1}]
  ]

And now just do


Thank you so much.

FYI your approach could work.  You just needed to put the  part specification in the s function, e.g.
a = NDEigenvalues[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + u[x], u[x], {x, -5, 5}, 4];
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == p y[t], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {t, 0, 10}, {p}];
s[m_, n_] := NIntegrate[x  pfun[a[[m]]][x] pfun[a[[n]]][x], {x, 0, 1}];

Evaluating:
Grid[Partition[Row[{{##}, s[##]}, "  "] & @@@ Tuples[Range[4], 2], 4],
  Frame -> All] 


